# how to run different Docker containers under different proxies

Tags: docker, proxy

Good afternoon.
Please tell me how I can run different Docker containers under different proxies.
I have several sets of working proxies: address, http(s) port, socks5 port, login and password.
I use Docker Desktop.
thanks

They get access via RDP to a remote VPS server where Ubuntu 20.04 is installed.

tried the option:
docker container -e http://username:password@address_proxxy:port_http(s)/ image_name

As a result, checking through services like https://whoer.net / I see that the ip under which I log on to the server (the ip that the VPS provider allocated to me)

Comment: up! help me, friends :)